# A* - Jquery + Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, grid

Estou fazendo um teste de **pathfinding** em jquery com JS, e dei uma empacada forte. Procurei vários lugares, mas não estou conseguindo raciocinar como iniciar a leitura dos "vizinhos" para fazer uma linha entre a "Origem" (quadrado onde o usuário clica) e o destino (quadrado[14,15])

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Até consigo fazer com que a área seja mapeada, mas não entendo como "sondar os vizinhos" para saber o melhor caminho.
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Aí vai o código:

```js
//ASTAR.JS
// function that builds a grid in the "container"
function createGrid(x) {
    for (var rows = 0; rows < x; rows++) {
        for (var columns = 0; columns < x; columns++) {
            $("#container").append("<div class='grid' id='"+rows+"_"+columns+"' onClick='createAStar("+rows+","+columns+")' nodevalue='1'></div>");
        };
    };
    $(".grid").width(320/x);
    $(".grid").height(320/x);
    $("#14_15").css("background-color", "blue");
    $("#14_15").remove("onClick");
    $("#14_15").css("cursor", "default" );
};

 

// function that prompts the user to select the number of boxes in a new grid
// the function then also creates that new grid

// create a 16x16 grid when the page loads
// creates a hover effect that changes the color of a square to black when the mouse passes over it, leaving a (pixel) trail through the grid
// allows the click of a button to prompt the user to create a new grid
$(document).ready(function() {
    createGrid(16);

});

function createAStar(xis, yps){

var goalX = 14;
var goalY = 15;
//var dx =  Math.abs(goalX - xis);
//var dy = Math.abs(goalY - xis);
//var distancia = Math.abs(dx+dy);
//alert(distancia);
//analisa_vizinhos();

for (ix = xis; ix <= goalX; ix++ ){
  
    for (iy = yps; iy <= goalY; iy++ ){
  
     $("#"+ix+"_"+iy).css("background-color","yellow");
   
} 
       
   
} 







}
```

```css
/* ESTILO.CSS */
body{

}
#container {
 position: relative;
 top: 30px;
 outline:2px solid #000;
 font-size: 0;
 margin:auto;
 height:320px;
 width:320px;
 padding: 0;
 border: none;
}
.grid{
 /*width: 10px;
 height: 10px;
 background-color: #cccccc;
 border: solid thin black;*/
 margin:0;
 padding:0;
 border:none;
 outline:1px solid #000;
 display:inline-block;
 cursor: pointer;

}

.node{

}

.neighbor{

}

.current{

}

.closed{

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 
 <script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="astar.js"></script>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="estilo.css">
</head>
<body>
 

<div id="container"></div>
 
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Tente explicar melhor com exemplos mais claros. Desta forma ficou complicado de saber o problema. O que seria `quadrado[14,15]`?

Comment: Eu estabeleci o quadrado [14,15] como o ponto FINAL. A ideia é que o usuário clique num quadrado e o JS calcule o menor caminho dele até o ponto FINAL

Comment: Vc quer criar uma linha reta de um quadrado pro outro?

Comment: não necessariamente reta, depende de onde o cara clicar, tipo assim: https://www.redblobgames.com/pathfinding/a-star/introduction.html